# how to enable user login after Offline domain join?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts

Is it possible to add computer from remote location to AD (windows 2008R2) and enable user login?

I've run DJOIN as described here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd392267(WS.10).aspx

but cannot login into domain after doing this, because my computer doesn't recognize my user.

I get *"there are currently no logon server available to service the logon request"* error.

P.S. I don't have VPN connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to establish a working connecting to the domain to log in as a domain user - at least for the first time, subsequent times may be able to use cached credentials if they're enabled.

You should probably log in as a local user, establish a VPN connection, hit 'switch user' and log in as a domain user.

Comment: what is the fastest way to establish VPN connection?

Comment: @Boris Let's put it this way: what method are you *supposed* to use to get a connection to the network with the domain controllers?

Comment: This is exactly what I ask you:) - How can I connect to my work Network and get VPN connection? Is any "5 minute" solution?

Comment: @Boris Do you manage the location with the domain controllers?  If so, you should set up a remote access mechanism like VPN that will allow for this computer in a different location to access the domain.

Comment: How to setup VPN to Active directory? I have RDP Connection to my DC. What I need to install in order to setup VPN connection to my home location? Is any Windows component or should I use some 3rd party software/hardware?

Comment: @Boris There are a ton of options for how to accomplish that.  Your network equipment might support it, or if you want to use just Windows then you should use VPN through RRAS, see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469733.aspx